# Please explain to me why $ \int_b p(a|b) db \neq p(a) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have one question that bugs me. How is it that:

$
\int_a p(a|b) da = \int_a \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} da = 1
$

but

$
\int_b p(a|b) db = \int_b \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} db \neq p(a)
$

I don't understand this because $ p(a,b) = p(b,a) $ and therefore

$
p(a|b) = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} \\
\Rightarrow p(a,b) = p(a|b) p(b) = p(b|a) p(a) = p(b,a)
$

and if I'm not mistaken:

$
p(a|b)p(b) = p(b|a)p(a) \\
\frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} p(b) = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(a)} p(a) \\
p(a,b) = p(a,b)
$

But how is it, that this is not correct:

$
\int_b p(a|b) db = \int_b \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} db = \int_b p(a,b) \frac{1}{p(b)} db = \int_b p(a,b) db \int_b \frac{1}{p(b)} db \\
\int_b p(a,b) db \int_b \frac{1}{p(b)} db = \int_b p(a,b) db *1 = \int_b p(a,b) =p(a)
$

which should hold because of the marginalization rule:

$
p(a) =\int_b p(a,b)
$

Comment: Why do you say $\int_b \frac{1}{p(b)} db =1$?

Comment: Summing over the probability of $p(b)$ should give $1$. Therefore the whole term should give one, doesn't it?

Comment: $0.4+0.6 = 1$ but $1/0.4+1/0.6 \neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What *is* true is that $\int_bp(a,b)db = p(a)$. Roughly speaking the probability that $a$ and $b$ occur, summed over all $b$, is just the probability that $a$ occurs.

I don't really understand what you are asserting to be true and what you are asserting to be false and what you are asking. But there are several mistakes in your post. Firstly, the equality $p(a|b) p(b) = p(b|a) p(b)$ is wrong, in general, unless $p(a)=p(b)$ or one of $p(a)$, $p(b)$ is 0. So is $\int_b p(a,b) \frac{1}{p(b)} db = \int_b p(a,b) db \int_b \frac{1}{p(b)} db$. And so is $\int1/p(b)db=1$, as you can easily convince yourself by considering a finite probability space. I am not sure: does that resolve your difficulties?

Comment: It is not true! $P(Dice=3|Dice Is Odd) = 1/3$ $P(Dice=3|Dice Is Even) = 0$ but $P(Dice=3)=1/6$. but $P(Dice=3)= P(DiceIsEven)P(Dice=3|Dice Is Even)+P(DiceIsOdd)P(Dice=3|Dice Is Odd)$

Comment: @hhsaffar I also think that it's true since $ \sum_{u} P(Dice = u) = 1 $ 
Alex B. Well.. are you sure that this $
p(a|b)p(b) = p(b|a)p(a) \\
\frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} p(b) = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(a)} p(a) \\
p(a,b) = p(a,b)
$ doesn't hold?

Comment: Yes Stefan but this is irrelevant, I editted my previous comment. I tried to explain more.

Comment: @hhsaffar You are right, of course. Sorry, corrected.

Comment: @hhsaffar Oh well, you mean under given $ DiceIsOdd $ and following to my _assumption_ I would end up with $p(d=3|odd) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{12} $ which is wrong since $ p(d = 3|odd) = \frac{1}{3} $ and therefore $p(d=3|odd) =\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6} = p(d = 3) $ right?

Comment: @AlexB. But $ p(a|b)p(b) = p(b|a)p(a) \Rightarrow p(a|b) = \frac{p(b|a)p(a)}{p(b)} $ which is the [Bayes'theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem#Statement_and_interpretation), isn't it? **edit:** sorry I made a mistake and corrected it in my question-post!